# Resampling audio file using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, audio, deep-learning, signal-processing

I have an audio file in wav format that has 22050 samples and sampling rate is 44.1 kHz. So the duration of the clip is .5 sec. When I am resampling the clip using:

```
Output=tfio.audio.resample(file,rate_in=44100,rate_out=16000)
```

The output wav file has 32000 sample and now the duration is 2 second.

But why and how it added extra samples and the duration of the clip is changed? Shouldn’t the duration remains the same as original clip?

Comment: [mre] required. in the current state of this question, the issue is not reproducible. -- perhaps file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pydub - AudioSegment functionality](https://audiosegment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/audiosegment.html) once.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment as am
resample= am.from_file(filepath, format='wav', frame_rate=44100)
resample= resample.set_frame_rate(16000)
resample.export(filepath, format='wav')
```

Reference - https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/232